# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 has frozen fields

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

After installing SP1 for Visual Studio 2008, various fields are frozen e.g. in Find & Replace dialog I can't type anything, or in Tools->External Tools all fields(texboxes) are frozen, can't type anything. Same with ReSharper, can't type anyting into any of its dialogs...

Do you know any workaround? If I restart visual studio it sometimes helps for a while sometimes not. Is this caused by SP1 or may it be ReSharper? Thanks.

Ok, so this problem occurs on my colleague computer which doesn't have ReSharper installed. Also this happens on both Vista and XP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was probably some combination of updates/plugins installed. after last updates it works correctly again.

Answer (score 1):

I would try reinstalling resharper if you haven't already.

Its impossible to say for certain without more details but I have installed vs sp1 numerous times on different os configurations without any issues however I have had problems with Reshaper so thats what I would bet on.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to run Visual Studio with turned on logging (devenv /out [log file name])
- Try to run Visual Studio with truned of add-ons (devenv /resetaddin Namespace.ClassName)

devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

This could help you spot the problem and maybe even fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your settings.
Tools--> Import and Export Settings...
from this dialog you can reset your IDE settings, choosing to Reset all environment settings to one of the default collections of settings. (C# Developer, Web Developer, Project Manager...)